# Is it too passive to start a sentence with 'To do something'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, passive-voice

> There are two types of pollution, local pollution and non-local pollution. **To quantify local pollution**, this paper adopted a mass balance approach.

Actually the two sentences are from two paragraphs. The information of the first sentence is from a previous paragraph, and the 'To quantify' sentence is placed as the first sentence of the following paragraph.

I know I can reframe this sentence like 'this paper adopted a mass balance approach to quantify local pollution'. But I feel it lost the emphasis. But my supervisor said the sentence is too passive...

Comment: By default, the "adverbial purpose" clause ***to quantify local pollution*** would come after the statement it applies to. "Fronting" it is entirely a stylistic choice (which arguably focuses attention on the *reason* rather than the action itself), but I've no idea what your supervisor might mean by saying that's "too passive". It's nothing to do with the normal *syntactic / grammatical* meaning of "passive".

Comment: A mass balance approach is used in this paper to quantify local pollution. Even though it is passive, it stresses the mass balance approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence

> To quantify local pollution, this paper adopted a mass balance approach.

is grammatically correct, although a present tense form would be better in my view:

> To quantify local pollution, this paper adopts a mass balance approach.

Strictly speaking, this is **not** in the passive voice, as a subject ("this paper") is present. An actual passive version would be:

> To quantify local pollution, a mass balance approach was used. (Note the absence of any agent here, even a personified thing such as "this paper")

However the sentence might sound more active, and be better writing, If this is recast to:

> To quantify local pollution, I use a mass balance approach in this paper.

If you want, or are required, to avoid "I", you can write "the author uses" or "the author has adopted" instead.

It is perfectly normal to start a sentence, or indeed a paragraph, with a statement of purpose introduced by "to".

> - To build a navy, pre-industrial people started by felling trees.
> - To make myself clear, I will avoid technical terms.

Comment: @ ColleenV quite true, i'll add it to the answer just for history and to inform later readers. of course that would not be **less** passive.

Comment: Yeah, it was just odd that the supervisor felt it was too passive, when it was actually in active voice, just not first person.

Comment: @ColleenV Well passivce voice is often used, esp in scientific papers, as part of that "never say 'I did' ", "obscure the agent" formula, which this text uses, although not via an actual passive construction. The supervisor may have conflated that style with "passive".

Comment: Yep. Maybe it would be beneficial to the author for the supervisor to pick a style guide to follow. Or, they can do what I have done in the past and add intentional awkwardness for the supervisor to correct. Some folks don’t enjoy being asked to review something and not having any improvements to suggest :)